# Array Clone & Copy still effect original

Tags: c#, arrays, copy, clone

I am passing in an array of objects which I want UNTOUCHED but for some reason no matter what I try the original array passed in is being changed.

```
private DSPPositionPeriodDO[] CompactShortTermData(DSPPositionPeriodDO[] data)
{
    DSPPositionPeriodDO[] resultArray = (DSPPositionPeriodDO[])data.Clone();
    int? hoursToAggBy = null;
    // it is short term, the data gets too much so decide how many
    // hours to aggregate by.
    var days = (_endDate - _startDate).TotalDays;
    if (days <= 3)
        hoursToAggBy = null;
    else if (days > 3 && days <= 7)
        hoursToAggBy = 1;
    else if (days > 7 && days <= 14)
        hoursToAggBy = 2;
    else if (days > 14 && days <= 21)
        hoursToAggBy = 3;
    else if (days > 21)
        hoursToAggBy = 4;

    if (hoursToAggBy != null)
    {
        // round down hours
        foreach (var posPeriod in resultArray)
        {
            var sl = posPeriod.StartLocal;
            sl = sl.AddHours(-(sl.Hour % hoursToAggBy.Value));
            sl = sl.AddMinutes(-sl.Minute);
            posPeriod.StartLocal = sl;
        }

        // group by entity & time -- get average
        var groupedData = resultArray.GroupBy(x => new
        {
            x.EntityId,
            x.EntityCode,
            x.StartLocal
        })
        .Select(g => new DSPPositionPeriodDO
        {
            EntityId = g.Key.EntityId,
            EntityCode = g.Key.EntityCode,
            StartLocal = g.Key.StartLocal,
            Volume = g.Average(v => v.Volume),
            AverageVolume = null
        });

        resultArray = groupedData.ToArray();
    }
}
```

I have tried to create a seperate copy like :

`var x = original.ToArray()`

`toList()`

`Clone()`

etc.

By `original` I mean the `data` object being passed in. I wish it not to be changed at all.

Comment: [Clone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.copy.aspx) in array performs shallow copy, i.e. it doesn't create a copy of objects itself

Comment: If you don't want that to happen then either the objects in the array must be value types or you must deep clone them manually.

Answer (score 1):

From [`Array.Clone`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.clone.aspx):

> The references in the new Array point to the same objects that the references in the original Array point to.

You need to clone *each* object into the new array.